# Загрузка текста из файла в текстовое поле

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы при загрузки страницы текст из файла загружался в текстовое поле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вкратце, что-то вроде:

```
<?php

$files = file('http://hashcode.ru/text.txt');

foreach ($files as $line) {   
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.$line.'">';
}

?>
```

Для многострочного:

```
<?php

$files = file('http://hashcode.ru/text.txt');

echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="45">';
foreach ($files as $line) {echo $line;}
echo '</textarea>';

?>
```

Comment: И, да, если хотите защитить себя от себя самого то можно использовать _htmlspecialchars($line)_ вместо _$line_

Answer (score 1):

Написать код, который:

1. прочитает файл и поместит содержимое в переменную $value
2. выведет текстовое поле со значением $value

это строчек 10-20 кода.

Answer (score 1):

К примеру я в этом случае воспользовался бы функцией [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Нужную строку по ее имени выводим в нужном месте! Я думаю что делать выборку по:

```
$line['name']
$line['secondname']
```

куда лучше чем:

```
$line[84]
$line[325]
```

если форычить или эксплодить, использовать `count()` и т.д... Извращаться над файлом можно как угодно, а выбрать верный способ иногда не всегда доходят либо руки, либо желание)

Answer (score 1):

Ахем... Господа, вы о чем?

```
<textarea><?=file_get_contents('somefile')?></textarea>
```

Либо, если запись в файл была без обработки данных:

```
<textarea><?=htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('somefile'))?></textarea>
```